# Need to parse/merge a csv and excel file, and create a new table with discrepancies between 2 datasets

Tags: python, excel, csv

Apologies, I am new to python and SO, and have been struggling with an issue.
I have a text and excel file that I need to merge, based off 2 columns that they have in common (date and id). They also have different column names for the same thing.

csv:

| test date | id | values 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-12 | a | 1 |
| 2024-03-13 | b | 2 |
| 2024-03-14 | c | 3 |

excel (headers are also on the fifth row):

| N/A 1 | id | N/A 2 | date | values 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| irrelevant | a | irrelevant | 3/12/2024 | 2 |
| irrelevant | b | irrelevant | 3/13/2024 | 4 |
| irrelevant | c | irrelevant | 3/14/2024 | 6 |

the goal is to create something like:

| date | id | value 1 | value 2 | discrepancy | Over 2? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-12 | a | 1 | 2 | 1 | no |
| 2024-03-13 | b | 2 | 4 | 2 | no |
| 2024-03-14 | c | 3 | 6 | 3 | yes |

I have to find what I tried, sorry, but i ended up having the code to csv to an excel file, and tried to merge from there. however i was never able to get my script to succesfully extract data from both sources at the same time. I will update this post with the code i tried as soon as possible, and thank you!

Comment: Are you using something like pandas to read in the two data sources into two data frames?

Comment: Yes, i attempted that first but was having a lot of trouble setting it up

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take it one step at a time it is relatively straight forward:

```py
import pandas
df1 = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
df2 = pandas.read_excel("test.xlsx", skiprows=4)

df3 = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on="id")
df3 = df3[["id", "date", "values 1", "values 2"]]
df3["discrepancy"] = df3["values 2"] - df3["values 1"]
df3["Over 2?"] = df3["discrepancy"] > 2
print(df3)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. Going through it a piece at a time was a lot easier than trying to tackle it all at once.